# Tomcat context reload after java source file was modified

Tags: tomcat, reload

when developing a web application that deployed on tomcat in eclipse, when the tomcat server is running if I modify a java source file and save it in eclipse, Tomcat will reload the web application, then the session is invalid I need to login again to test.

I think it's a big troube, so I want to know is there anyway to configure tomcat or use another application server can avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can open Tomcat configuration in Eclipse and choose `Never publish automatically` option.  The default is `Automatically publish when resources change`

Comment: It may be not enough, I had also to go to WebModules tab and set 'Auto Reload' = disabled to get rid of it.